# Replacing Windows with Gentoo on a dual boot

Tags: partition, windows, dual-boot, gentoo

I have a laptop with a Windows/Ubuntu dual boot. I haven't touched Windows since I bought the computer 3 years ago and thought I'd replace it with Gentoo. My understanding from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/794/894191) is that I should create a live USB to boot up with, then use Gparted to delete the Windows partition. My question is, do I then have to format the partition as a particular file system (e.g., ext4) before I can install Gentoo? Alternatively, do I even have to delete the Windows partition or could I simply overwrite the existing Windows partition with Gentoo immediately? Also, presumably I should keep WinRE_DRV just in case I'd like to recover Windows in the future?

Comment: After following the directions in the answer to delete the Windows partition, you can proceed with Gentoo and select the filesystem during installation.

Comment: If you already have Ubuntu on the machine, you can install Gentoo from within Ubuntu -- you wouldn't need to boot from any live media.  Take a look at Gentoo handbook, that includes topics around selecting the filesystem:  https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64  Just be very careful when selecting partitions to wipe.